# Linux terminal without keyboard (only joystick arrows and enter)

Tags: raspberry-pi, terminal-emulator, input-method

Dear stackexchange community,

I am developing a project on RaspberryPi using Retropie for games, and I would like to offer linux command line functions. The Raspberry is embedded in a case and you only have joystick controls like in a videogame console. Actually you can access root terminal with `ssh` or connecting a usb keyboard, but what I want to have is command line control just using the joystick.

Something similar to vintage arcades, that you fill the data about your records just moving the arrows up and down and selecting every letter.

Is there any linux terminal with some kind of accesibility function that allows you something similar? For example using linux emulated in android, using UserLand app, you have a terminal where you can press some arrows (you have the touchscreen) and also a screen keyboard appears (that maybe there is a way to use only with joystick, not with touchscreen).

Another possible solution would be to prepare a dialog or whiptail script...

Thanks in advance

Ecofintech Coop

Comment: Update question to tell us if the terminal will be running in a windowing system, and if so which one?

Comment: For now I'm thinking to use dialog, launched from headerless raspbian. And I think Im on the way researching about xpad controller for managin the input, like in RetroArch.

Another option for research can be this:
https://github.com/CypherpunkArmory/UserLAnd/tree/master/termux-app